# Does Win7 software exist that logs the name of windows with focus

Tags: windows-7, logging, focus

I'd like to buy a Windows 7 program that locally logs the name of all windows that get focus, along with the duration of focus. [www.realtime-spy.com](http://www.realtime-spy.com) appears to do the job (and more), but it stores it's data on a remote server.